# Form.clientScriptModulePath - NetSuite

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a client script which runs well when I create it as a client script record.
But it doesn't work when I execute in UserEvent Script using Form.clientScriptModulePath.
Unders are my ClientScript and UserEvent Script.

```
EntryPoint.beforeLoad = (context) => {
        const LOGTITLE = "beforeload " + context.newRecord.id;
        
        try {
            if(context.form && context.type == context.UserEventType.EDIT) {
                var currentForm = context.form;
                currentForm.clientScriptFileId = 314223;
                //currentForm.clientScriptModulePath = './ZP.ProofOfConcept.TEST.CS.js';
              
                currentForm.addField({
                    id: 'custpage_paymentoption',
                    type: 'SELECT',
                    label: 'Custom Payment Option',
               });
            }
        } catch (e) {
            log.error(LOGTITLE, JSON.stringify(e));
        }

        return true;
    }
```

```
EntryPoint.fieldChanged = (scriptContext) => {
        const LOGTITLE = "fieldChanged " + scriptContext.currentRecord.id;
        
        try {
            var record = scriptContext.currentRecord;
        
            if (scriptContext.fieldId == 'custpage_paymentoption') {
                var currentOption = record.getValue({
                    fieldId: 'custpage_paymentoption',
                })
                log.debug('currentOption', currentOption);

                record.setValue({
                    fieldId: 'paymentoption',
                    value: currentOption,
                    ignoreFieldChange: true,
                    forceSyncSourcing: true
                });
            }
        } catch (e) {
            log.error(LOGTITLE, JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    };
```

Please let me know if someone knows the solution.

It works well if I creat two script records for ClientScript and UserEvent script.
But if I create only one script record for UserEventScript and upload the ClientScript to UserEventScript it doesn't work.

Comment: Please, post the full scripts: the client one and the user even one. If those are the real full contents of the scripts — then they won't work for many reasons. The first one: they don't conform to the syntax of SuiteScript, which, AFAIK, requires each script to start with a comment with meta information like: script type, suitescript version and the scope